# is there a infinite loop in this happy number solution in leetcode?

Tags: algorithm

[Here](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/) is the happy number question in leetcode

This is [one](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/discuss/56917/My-solution-in-C(-O(1)-space-and-no-magic-math-property-involved-)) of the solution

Using Floyd Cycle detection algorithm.

```
int digitSquareSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0, tmp;
    while (n) {
        tmp = n % 10;
        sum += tmp * tmp;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

bool isHappy(int n) {
    int slow, fast;
    slow = fast = n;
    do {
        slow = digitSquareSum(slow);
        fast = digitSquareSum(fast);
        fast = digitSquareSum(fast);
    } while(slow != fast);
    if (slow == 1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Is there a chance to have infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

There would only be an infinite loop if iterating `digitSquareSum` could grow without bounds. But when it is called with an n digit number the result is always smaller than 100n so this does not happen because for n >= 4 the result is always smaller than the number used as input.

All that ignores that integers in the computer in most languages cannot be arbitrarily large, you would get an integer overflow if the result could grow mathematically to infinity. The result would then be likely wrong but there would still not be an infinite loop.